# How to make nearly 1,70,000 marker dots on JMapViewer?

Tags: swing, awt, openstreetmap, jmapviewer, jxmapviewer

I have real-time (or nearer real time) data of flight. I want to make dots based on lat-long basis. But there are too many dots to represent and my map stuck while reading:

Queues:

1. Rather than painting whole screen tiles I want to repainting only one tile.

   and
2. While I am adding 1,70,000 to `map.addMapMarker(new MapMarkerDot(Color,lat,lon))` - facing the problem that `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`.

What is an easy way to solve my problem?

Comment: By *"1,70,000"* DYM 1.7 million or 170 thousand?

Comment: *"What is an easy way to solve my problem?"* Hire someone. It's *always* the easiest way. If you want to solve it with (or without) our help, don't ask for 'easy'.

Comment: As an aside, if the points form a line, I doubt it will need more than 1700 (one thousand, seven hundred) points, so you might skip the ones in between those 1700 (spread evenly from first to last point). Having said that, it seems not to be a problem with the memory needed to hold those points, but something to do with threads. You did *read the docs* on [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html), right?

Comment: If your question is not an exact duplicate, you'll surely want to use the approach shown [there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37193636/230513). In any case, please edit your question to answer @AndrewThompson's question and include a [mcve] that shows your current approach.