# animation on map with jmapframe - geotools

Tags: java, swing, animation, gis, geotools

I am using [geotools](http://www.geotools.org/) library to animate a polygon on a map.
By using **JMapPane** it is possible to do animation smoothly. ex:[AnimatedMapPane](http://svn.osgeo.org/geotools/tags/2.6.1/demo/example/src/main/java/org/geotools/demo/swing/AnimatedMapPane.java)

However, the problem with it is that I can not use it with **JMapFrame** and I have to use **JFrame**.
I want to use JMapFrame because it offers a lot more features compared JFrame like showing layers, zoom buttons etc.

Can I add JMapPane as a layer to JMapFrame? (A layer for map, another layer for animation objects)

In addition, I considered making dynamic layer to make animation. But as indicated [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10212/geotools-dynamic-layer) it causes flickering and answer suggests the usage of JMapPane.

Comment: A complete example using [tag:jmapviewer] is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36783672/230513).

Comment: sorry but i think jmapviever and jmapframe are totally different things. (OpenStreetMap/Geotools)

Comment: Right, but others might like to see a `SwingWorker` example in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you would extend JMapFrame and override the constructor to change the `MapPane` to be an `AnimatedMapPane` but `mapPane` is a private variable. If you put in an [enhancement request](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/developer/procedures/contribute.html) (preferable with a clean up to use `getMapPane()` through out and a `setMapPane(pane)` method) I could review and apply it.

Alternatively you could copy [`JMapFrame`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/unsupported/swing/src/main/java/org/geotools/swing/JMapFrame.java) into a new class and make a single change to the type of `MapPane` created at [line 202](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/unsupported/swing/src/main/java/org/geotools/swing/JMapFrame.java#L202) and be done.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will give it a try.